# Is it possible to view the content of app bundle(.app file)

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to view the content of compiled app bundle(.app file)?
check if the app uses some kind library(.a file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.app` file as simply a file wrapper, a folder with a extension.

Assuming you're using Mac OS X, you can view the content of a file wrapper by right clicking on the `.app` file and selecting "Show Package Contents".